# Is masturbation haram , Halal , makruh or what?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

Assalamu alaikom brothers & sisters

Recently I’ve been very confused on the topic of masturbation in Islam , I’ve seen people saying it’s haram in all cases , makruh , mashbooh, permissible if you’re not married , have an illness etc

There’s so many different opinions on this topic and since there’s no direct mention of it in the Quran and Hadith it’s even more confusing

Can you please help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Masterbation questions have been asked a million times in here. Please look it up.

Answer (score -2):

Great question as many of us have fallen to the victim of pornography and therein leads to masturbation.

> And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way. [17:32]

In this particular ayah, Allah said, **not to approach** but he didn't say **not to do** *unlawful sexual intercourse*. Because the thing is Allah made us with some vulnerabilities and this is one of them so Allah knows even if you approach this act you will commit **fornication**. That's why Allah said **Do Not Approach**.

Now, some will argue about the definition of *Sextual Intercourse*.Well, let's get to that, according to google it has two definitions

1. Special
2. Typical
   [image: Definition of Sexual Intercourse]

Take what suits you best but I'll go with the typical one cause that's what all matters in the end **Orgasm**. So, I think it's clear that **Masturbation** too is forbidden and sinful act.

Some people will also imply that in **Islam** **Haram/Forbidden** things are clear but there is not one mention of **Masturbation** being **Haram/Forbidden** in the **Hadith** of **Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)**. So, how can you say *it's haram?* unless there is a clear mention of it.Well, I won't argue about that, cause enemies of Islam always trying to distract us from the transparent to leave us astray. Take your time and do your research if you're not satisfied with my answer.

[For more go to this website](https://fightthenewdrug.org/).

Allah knows best.

Comment: The Qur'an is written in Arabic. Basing a ruling on an English dictionary definition of an English translated term to explain the intent and meaning of the original Arabic text is extremely sloppy scholarship. Especially when you effectively ignore that actual definition.

Comment: You are welcome to come up with many definitions of **Sexual Intercourse**. And as far as I am concerned **Sexual Intercourse** has no other meaning rather than _culminating in orgasm and ejaculation of semen._